# How to use public key in azure devops pipline copy files over SSH

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use Azure DevOps to deploy a Laravel application to a Bluehost website.

The idea is that when I commit changes to my repo, that a pipeline will trigger and will run composer, then deploy to the website.

The issue I am having, is that authentication with Bluehost fails, even after I've authorized the SSH key(I may only authorize public keys).

> Error: Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: All configured authentication methods failed..

My theory, is that DevOps is generating a new public key to log into BlueHost, which fails to authenticate(as it's not the authorized public key).

I see that there is an "Install SSH Key" task I can use; however, I don't understand how to use the downloaded key in the "Copy over SSH" task.

How can I use a public key in an Azure DevOps pipeline Copy over SSH task?

Comment: Can you share you pipeline code ? i am trying to deploy to cpanel also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prerequisites of using `Copy Files Over SSH` task are as below:

- The task supports use of an SSH key pair to connect to the remote
  machine(s).
- **The public key must be pre-installed or copied to the remote
  machine(s).**

When you use [Install SSH Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops) task, the SSH keys are installed on the remote machine. You don't need to download it in `Copy Files Over SSH` task. Check the following example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops#example-setup-using-github

Comment: Oh, so, install SSH key isn't installing onto the machine handling deployment. It's installing a key onto the remote machine? (Which is already done).

I guess my question is, how do I use Copy Files Over SSH with the public key I have added to the remote machine?

Comment: Public key should has been installed on your remote machine. When you create SSH service connection, you need to provide User name + Password, or provide Private key. Check following links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-ssh, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops. In addition, this task is intended for target machines running Linux. Is your target machines running Linux?

Comment: How's your issue going?

Comment: I apologize, I got sick there for a while. I was able to bypass it by deploying with FTPS instead. 
Issue is not resolved, as Authorization still fails. The target machine is indeed running linux, and the public key is authorized.

Comment: I Was able to make it work today
1. I created an SSH key pair, and uploaded both to Bluehost via the CPanel
2. I authorized the public key.
3. I backed up my dev machines local ssh keys, and ssh'd into the server with the private key.
4. Upon success, I then copied the contents of the private key into the SSH service in devops.
5. I ran only the "Copy Files over SSH" for my SSH connection, using the previously edited SSH Service. (As you suggested)
6. I ran the pipeline, which passed! (I wonder if all along I had miscopied something)