# Azure pipeline connect to an ssh server and then copy files into it

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm actually trying to use Azure DevOps pipelines to send files into an external server using ssh.

First of all, I uploaded my private key that I use to connect to the server following that doc : [Secure file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops).

Then, I follow the connection like with that doc [Install SSH keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops).

Then, I run a node.js project to extract dist files.

And finally, I want to copy my dist files into the server using SSH like this doc explain it [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops).

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    cd front-react
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

# Install SSH key
# Install an SSH key prior to a build or deployment
- task: InstallSSHKey@0
  name: localssh
  inputs:
    knownHostsEntry: 'xxx@1.1.1.1'
    sshPublicKey: $(id_rsa)
    sshKeySecureFile: privkey_file

- task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: localssh
    contents: 'front-react/build/'
    targetFolder: '/testssh'
    readyTimeout: '20000'
```

The problem is I don't know how to use my SSH connection into the **sshEndpoint** attribute.

This is related to this post [How to use public key in azure devops pipline copy files over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64506999/how-to-use-public-key-in-azure-devops-pipline-copy-files-over-ssh) but it's not explicit how to link the installed ssh and copy ssh using that connection.

Answer (score 2):

The public key is stored on your remote machine. You need to upload the private key to your SSH service connection (navigate `Project settings > Service connections`)

[image]

After that, you can use Copy files over SSH task to copy files:

```
- task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
  displayName: 'Securely copy files to the remote machine'
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: test
    sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    targetFolder: /home/azureuser/test
    cleanTargetFolder: true
    failOnEmptySource: true
```

Please note that: I didn't use Install SSH Key task and I used self-hosted agent. It worked on my side. If you want to use install SSH key task, please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this way but I can't establish the ssh connection. I have to disable the new service connection from preview features ?