# Add SSH service connection using a build pipeline in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ssh, pipeline, serviceconnection

How can I add a new SSH service connection using a build pipeline in Azure DevOps? I would like to specify the username ip and key and grant access to all pipelines

SSH service connection using the pipeline. Didnt get any results to do this!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know. It is not possible to automate creating an SSH service connection.

Normally Microsoft offers [`az devops service-endpoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/service-endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest) command line to create a service connection for azure resource manager or GitHub. But does not offer SSH creation. If someone else can show something else I will remove my answer.

---

Original answer:

From your project setting, click on Service connections, and search for SSH

[image]

You can add the parameter for your ssh and then at the end check Grant access permission to all pipelines:

[image]

With that said there is an example of [Azure pipeline connect to an ssh server and then copy files into it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67905601/azure-pipeline-connect-to-an-ssh-server-and-then-copy-files-into-it)

Comment: I want to automate this using a build pipeline. not from the ui

Comment: It is not possible, check my answer update. Please make your question more clear.

Comment: ok. then is there any way to build a ssh conenction and run a script directly from pipeline using the command line module? meaning run the ssh command providing the keys and required details and run a specific script on the remote machine?

Comment: you can always run a customized script either in PowerShell or Bash script, I have not tried it for SSH. So it is a matter of trying until you get it to work.

Comment: I've added a bash script module and added ssh command  sudo ssh -t -t -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@ip
sudo mkdir /home/ec2-user/test .. The pipeline is able to login as it shows last login as an output after running pipeline. After that it hangs, nothing happens further

Comment: The ssh connection is happening. but its stuck up after that. How to get it to run the next command or script

Comment: hangging could be sign of firewall issue

Comment: I suggest you make a new question specific regarding the new script in sted of comments here, hence we are moving away from the original question.