# How to upload files from Azure Pipeline published artifact to remote WAS Server using Azure releases?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, websphere, azure-releases

I have a pipeline, on successful running it will [publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zusG.png) an .ear file as an artifact, which can be downloaded.

I am manually downloading it and then upload it to a folder in a remotely hosted WAS server to deploy. WAS Server is shared an I have only access to upload files into one of the subfolders.

WAS Server needs to be accessed by username and a password and its details are like:

**IP:** https://sample.domain.net
**Port:** 3442
**Subfolder with write premission:** dropzone/Sample1/Sample2/Sample

These are all the information available. I want to automate this process.

How can I copy the file directly from the published pipeline artifact to WAS server dropzone, using Azure releases?

Comment: If you are dropping files to the folder, it has nothing to do with WAS. Just use scp

Comment: @Gas both are window machines, so scp means what?

Comment: Please try to use the [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-over-ssh-v0?view=azure-pipelines).

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT I'm getting Error: Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\WorkingFloder\01\_tasks\CopyFilesOverSSH_67cec91b-0351-4c2f-8465-h3446356d6\0.229.0\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:1013:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  level: 'client-timeout'
}..

Comment: @codingEnthu, for this error, you can refer [this answer and comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64534596/16162444).  By the way, the  scp mentioned by Gas should be [Secure copy protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy_protocol). Hope it helps.

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT thank you. Will try those

Comment: Hi @codingEnthu, how is this issue going now? If it is not solved, you can share the latest progress to get more help. If it's solved, you can post an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT it is still failing, we can connect to the IP but the specific port number request is failing. Maybe there is no service running on port is the issue

Answer (score 0):

In your Azure DevOps organization, you can install and use the [**IBM WebSphere Application Server**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.ibm-websphere) extension provided by Microsoft.

This extension provides a pipeline task "**IBM WebSphere Deployment**" that can allow you to automate deploy your application to IBM WebSphere Application Servers (WAS).

This task provides two methods to connect with WAS Server:

[image]

- If you select "**`Service Endpoint Connection`**", you need to go to **Project Settings** > **Service connections** > **New service connection**, create an **IBM WebSphere** service connection for use.

  [image]
- If you select "**`Enter Connection Details`**", you can directly provide the **Username**, **Password** and **Host Address** on the task.

  [image]